# Android canvas draw rectangle

Tags: android, android-canvas

how to draw empty rectangle with etc. borderWidth=3 and borderColor=black and part within rectangle don't have content or color. Which function in Canvas to use

```
void drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)

void drawRect(RectF rect, Paint paint)

void drawRect(Rect r, Paint paint)
```

Thanks.

I try this example

```
Paint myPaint = new Paint();
myPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
myPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
c.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, myPaint);
```

It draws rectangle and fill it with black color but I want just "frame" around
like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Try `paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE)`?

Answer (score 129):

Assuming that "*part within rectangle don't have content color*" means that you want different fills within the rectangle; you need to draw a rectangle within your rectangle then with stroke width 0 and the desired fill colour(s).

For example:

**DrawView.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);            
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawRect(33, 60, 77, 77, paint );
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawRect(33, 33, 77, 60, paint );

    }

}
```

The activity to start it:

**StartDraw.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class StartDraw extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(drawView);

    }
}
```

...will turn out this way:

[image]

Comment: Actually this is what I need screencast.com/t/oFYF5kGtw5B that red rectangle after I draw all just to add that rectangle is that possible?

Comment: This is the solution
paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think DonGru and Juan gave a great explanation here.. but the exact one line answer to what author is asking for has been provided below by @Yuck -- 
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE)

Comment: This answer doesn't fit with the answer. It doesn't show the corrent answer. Pandur's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 13):

```
//white background
canvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255);
//border's properties
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setStrokeWidth(0);        
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);         
canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, paint);
```

Answer (score 10):

Create a new class **`MyView, Which extends View`**. Override the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method to draw rectangle on `Canvas`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class MyView extends View {

 Paint paint;
 Path path;

 public MyView(Context context) {
  super(context);
  init();
 }

 public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  init();
 }

 public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  init();
 }

 private void init(){
  paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
  paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onDraw(canvas);

  canvas.drawRect(30, 50, 200, 350, paint);
  canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 300, 400, paint);
  //drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint)

 }

}
```

Then Move your Java activity to `setContentView()` using our custom View, MyView.Call this way.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(new MyView(this));
  }
```

For more details you can visit here

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Answer (score 6):

```
paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

paint.setColor(BLACK);
```

and either one of your `drawRect` should work.

Answer (score 2):

The code is fine just setStyle of paint as STROKE

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if this is too late, but the way I solved this was to draw four thin rectangles that together made up a one big border.  Drawing the border with one rectangle seems to be undoable since they're all opaque, so you should draw each edge of the border separately.

Comment: Or two rectangles one inside other :)

Comment: Or a circle, a circle of the background color, a three segmented drawLines() and a rectangle, for the fourth line.