# Android - How to make google Maps display a polyline that animates sequenctial flashing dots

Tags: google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am searching for a way to animate the dots between two markers on a google map in android device.
So what i want in the end is the following line between the two images:

[image]

and it would be used like this typical google polyline implementation:

[image]

lets say there is a point A and a Point B.  if im directing the user to point B, then the line animates to from point A to point B so the user knows to walk in this direction.

to achieve this i thought i could get the points out of the polyLine and remove them and add them back
rapidily.  so lets say i had 5 points in the polyLine, i would remove position 1 , then put it back, then remove position 2, and put it back, to simulate this animation.

but it does not work . once hte polyline is set it seems i cannot alter it. you have any suggestions ?

```
val dotPattern = Arrays.asList(Dot(), Gap(convertDpToPixel(7).toFloat()))
            val polyLineOptions: PolylineOptions = PolylineOptions()
                    .add(usersLocation)
                    .add(users_destination)
                    .pattern(dotPattern)
                    .width(convertDpToPixel(6).toFloat())
            dottedPolyLine = googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions)
```

dottedPolyLine?.points?.removeAt(1) // here as a test if my idea i try removing a point but it looks like a point here means current location or destination so there always 2. i thought a point would be one of the dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MapView-based custom view View Canvas animationlike in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53941984/6950238):

> This approach requires
>   [`MapView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView)-based
>   [custom
>   view](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components),
>   that implements:
>
> - drawing over the MapView canvas;
> - customizing line styles (circles instead of a simple line);
> - binding path to Lat/Lon coordinates of map
> - performing animation.
>
> Drawing over the MapView needs to override `dispatchDraw()`.
>   Customizing line styles needs
>   [`setPathEffect()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setPathEffect(android.graphics.PathEffect))
>   method of
>   [`Paint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint)
>   class that allows to create create path for "circle stamp" (in
>   pixels), which will repeated every "advance" (in pixels too),
>   something like that:
>
> mCircleStampPath = new Path();  mCircleStampPath.addCircle(0,0,
>   CIRCLE_RADIUS, Path.Direction.CCW);   mCircleStampPath.close();
>
> For binding path on screen to Lat/Lon coordinates
>   [`Projection.toScreenLocation()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection.html#toScreenLocation(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng))
>   needed, that requires
>   [`GoogleMap`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap)
>   object so custom view should implements `OnMapReadyCallback` for
>   receive it. For continuous animation
>   [`postInvalidateDelayed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidateDelayed(long))
>   can be used.

but not draw path directly from point A to point B, but from point A to point C that animated from A to B. To get current position of point C you can use [`SphericalUtil.interpolate()`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#interpolate-LatLng-LatLng-double-) from [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/). Something like that:

```
public class EnhancedMapView extends MapView implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final float CIRCLE_RADIUS = 10;
    private static final float CIRCLE_ADVANCE = 3.5f * CIRCLE_RADIUS;   // spacing between each circle stamp
    private static final int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 30;
    private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 10000;


    private OnMapReadyCallback mMapReadyCallback;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private LatLng mPointA;
    private LatLng mPointB;
    private LatLng mPointC;

    private float mCirclePhase = 0;                                     // amount to offset before the first circle is stamped
    private Path mCircleStampPath;
    private Paint mPaintLine;
    private final Path mPathFromAtoC = new Path();
    private long mStartTime;
    private long mElapsedTime;

    public EnhancedMapView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public EnhancedMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public EnhancedMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public EnhancedMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable GoogleMapOptions options) {
        super(context, options);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        drawLineFomAtoB(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        // perform one shot animation
        mElapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartTime;
        if (mElapsedTime < ANIMATION_DURATION) {
            postInvalidateDelayed(1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND);
        }
    }

    private void drawLineFomAtoB(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mGoogleMap == null || mPointA == null || mPointB == null) {
            return;
        }

        // interpolate current position
        mPointC = SphericalUtil.interpolate(mPointA, mPointB, (float) mElapsedTime / (float)ANIMATION_DURATION);

        final Projection mapProjection = mGoogleMap.getProjection();
        final Point pointA = mapProjection.toScreenLocation(mPointA);
        final Point pointC = mapProjection.toScreenLocation(mPointC);

        mPathFromAtoC.rewind();
        mPathFromAtoC.moveTo(pointC.x, pointC.y);
        mPathFromAtoC.lineTo(pointA.x, pointA.y);

        // change phase for circles shift
        mCirclePhase = (mCirclePhase < CIRCLE_ADVANCE)
                ? mCirclePhase + 1.0f
                : 0;
        mPaintLine.setPathEffect(new PathDashPathEffect(mCircleStampPath, CIRCLE_ADVANCE, mCirclePhase, PathDashPathEffect.Style.ROTATE));

        canvas.drawPath(mPathFromAtoC, mPaintLine);
    }

    private void init() {
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        mCircleStampPath = new Path();
        mCircleStampPath.addCircle(0,0, CIRCLE_RADIUS, Path.Direction.CCW);
        mCircleStampPath.close();

        mPaintLine = new Paint();
        mPaintLine.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaintLine.setStrokeWidth(1);
        mPaintLine.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaintLine.setPathEffect(new PathDashPathEffect(mCircleStampPath, CIRCLE_ADVANCE, mCirclePhase, PathDashPathEffect.Style.ROTATE));

        // start animation
        mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();    
        postInvalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback) {
        mMapReadyCallback = callback;
        super.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraMove() {
                invalidate();
            }
        });
        if (mMapReadyCallback != null) {
            mMapReadyCallback.onMapReady(googleMap);
        }
    }

    public void setPoints(LatLng pointA, LatLng pointB) {
        mPointA = pointA;
        mPointB = pointB;
    }

}
```

NB! This is just idea, not full tested code.

Comment: your work is genius. appreciate your help. one thing i need. i dont want the line to touch the markers so much. as as soon as the line reaches the markers it should not show anymore. how can i control that ? i wish there was  like a z-index to make the markers appear over the line. what do you suggest ?  i just need the line to not cross ontop of the markers both.

Comment: @j2emanue Thanx, but I'm just Android engineer :) Because of drawing directly on View canvas there is no possibilities to take into account Google Maps z-index. Possible workaround - convert markers LatLng into screen coords (via `mapProjection.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());`) and draw markers manually on canvas after `drawLineFomAtoB(canvas);` call. Marker can be drawn as bitmap like in answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13361231/6950238) question. Or you can draw line slightly afrer point A and slightly before point B to avoid intersection with marker.