# Google Maps - making an animation like grab app to show the path direction

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to make an animation which does a moving marker along a path.

so i thought about how to do this using a marker that is slightly darker than the path line.  and removing and updating its position very slowly so that it looks like its moving.  but i just don't think that's what's happening in the video. because the market takes on the shape of the path entirely. it flows perfectly.

here is what i have so far:

```
fun showLineAtUsersLocation(loc_destination: LatLng) {
    val currentLoc = activity.getCachedCurrentLoc()
        val pattern = Arrays.asList(Dash(), Gap(convertDpToPixel(6).toFloat()))
        val polyLineOptions: PolylineOptions = PolylineOptions()
                .add(currentLoc)
                .add(loc_destination)
                .geodesic(true)
                .pattern(pattern)
                .width(convertDpToPixel(8).toFloat())
        googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions)
}
```

but this is just showing an overlay line from one point to the other.  not really following a path.  What should i be looking for instead?

I saw that ios has a has a [class good for this GMSStyleSpan](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_style_span) to manipuate the image. but i cannot find the equivalent in android. i dont see a span class or style class i can get a reference to any ideas on this ? or even with AnomatedVectorDrawable on the marker instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such (and actually any kind of) animation you can use View Canvas animation. This approach requires [`MapView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView)-based [custom view](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components), that implements:

- drawing over the MapView canvas;
- customizing line styles (circles instead of a simple line);
- binding path to Lat/Lon coordinates of map
- performing animation.

Drawing over the MapView needs to override `dispatchDraw()`. Customizing line styles needs [`setPathEffect()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setPathEffect(android.graphics.PathEffect)) method of [`Paint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint) class that allows to create create path for "circle stamp" (in pixels), which will repeated every "advance" (in pixels too), something like that:

```
mCircleStampPath = new Path();
mCircleStampPath.addCircle(0,0, CIRCLE_RADIUS, Path.Direction.CCW);
mCircleStampPath.close();
```

For binding path on screen to Lat/Lon coordinates [`Projection.toScreenLocation()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection.html#toScreenLocation(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)) needed, that requires [`GoogleMap`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap) object so custom view should implements `OnMapReadyCallback` for receive it. For continuous animation [`postInvalidateDelayed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidateDelayed(long)) can be used. So, with full source code of `MapView`-based custom `EnhancedMapView`:

```
public class EnhancedMapView extends MapView implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final float CIRCLE_RADIUS = 10;
    private static final float CIRCLE_ADVANCE = 3.5f * CIRCLE_RADIUS;   // spacing between each circle stamp
    private static final int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 30;

    private OnMapReadyCallback mMapReadyCallback;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private LatLng mPointA;
    private LatLng mPointB;

    private float mCirclePhase = 0;                                     // amount to offset before the first circle is stamped
    private Path mCircleStampPath;
    private Paint mPaintLine;
    private final Path mPathFromAtoB = new Path();

    public EnhancedMapView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public EnhancedMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public EnhancedMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public EnhancedMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable GoogleMapOptions options) {
        super(context, options);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        drawLineFomAtoB(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        // perform continuous animation
        postInvalidateDelayed(1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND);
    }

    private void drawLineFomAtoB(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mGoogleMap == null || mPointA == null || mPointB == null) {
            return;
        }

        final Projection mapProjection = mGoogleMap.getProjection();
        final Point pointA = mapProjection.toScreenLocation(mPointA);
        final Point pointB = mapProjection.toScreenLocation(mPointB);

        mPathFromAtoB.rewind();
        mPathFromAtoB.moveTo(pointB.x, pointB.y);
        mPathFromAtoB.lineTo(pointA.x, pointA.y);

        // change phase for circles shift
        mCirclePhase = (mCirclePhase < CIRCLE_ADVANCE)
                ? mCirclePhase + 1.0f
                : 0;
        mPaintLine.setPathEffect(new PathDashPathEffect(mCircleStampPath, CIRCLE_ADVANCE, mCirclePhase, PathDashPathEffect.Style.ROTATE));

        canvas.drawPath(mPathFromAtoB, mPaintLine);
    }

    private void init() {
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        mCircleStampPath = new Path();
        mCircleStampPath.addCircle(0,0, CIRCLE_RADIUS, Path.Direction.CCW);
        mCircleStampPath.close();

        mPaintLine = new Paint();
        mPaintLine.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaintLine.setStrokeWidth(1);
        mPaintLine.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaintLine.setPathEffect(new PathDashPathEffect(mCircleStampPath, CIRCLE_ADVANCE, mCirclePhase, PathDashPathEffect.Style.ROTATE));

        postInvalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback) {
        mMapReadyCallback = callback;
        super.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraMove() {
                invalidate();
            }
        });
        if (mMapReadyCallback != null) {
            mMapReadyCallback.onMapReady(googleMap);
        }
    }

    public void setPoints(LatLng pointA, LatLng pointB) {
        mPointA = pointA;
        mPointB = pointB;
    }

}
```

`MainActivity` like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey";
    static final LatLng MAIDAN = new LatLng(50.450891, 30.522843);
    static final LatLng SOPHIA = new LatLng(50.452967, 30.514498);

    static final LatLng INITIAL_MAP_CENTER = new LatLng(50.452011, 30.518766);
    static final int INITIAL_ZOOM = 15;

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private EnhancedMapView mMapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }

        mMapView = (EnhancedMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);
        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mGoogleMap = googleMap;
                mMapView.setPoints(MAIDAN, SOPHIA);
                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(INITIAL_MAP_CENTER, INITIAL_ZOOM));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (mapViewBundle == null) {
            mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
            outState.putBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
        }

        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mMapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mMapView.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mMapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

and `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.test.just.googlemapsgeneral.views.EnhancedMapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

you got something like:

[image: animated line]

NB! You should use [`Path`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path) instead of drawing lines. And that is just approach, not complete solution.

Comment: hey, how would i make the line move faster ? is there a way to control the speed of it ?

Comment: @j2emanue increase constant in `mCirclePhase + 1.0f` line: `mCirclePhase + 2.0f` increase speed to 2x.