# show a rectangular box in the absolute center in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show a rectangular box in the absolute center in a layout with height h/3 and width 3w/5 (w: width of screen, h: height of screen). Please help me to find a solution, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can adjust it using linear layout using weight 
i have pasted a sample code below hope this helps.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/transparent"
 >
```

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="5"
 />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/desiredbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/skyblueBackground" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="5"
 />
 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah. This is possible using a Relative layout parent and another layout(your box) inside that positioned as center. and the width and height of your box can be mentioned in java, rather than in xml.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom view which extends the `View` class and override the `onDraw()` method to create the desired rectangle. you can refer to: [Android canvas draw rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344497/android-canvas-draw-rectangle) to get the general idea.

If your question is: How to position a view inside a container - add this in the constructor of the parent view:

```
    final ViewTreeObserver vto = this.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // here, the dimensions of the parent are available
                int containerHeight = instance.getHeight();
                int containerWidth = instance.getWidth();       

                childView.setY(containerHeight/3);
                childView.setX(containerWidth * 3 / 5);
                instance.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

            }       
        }
    });
```

where `instance` is a reference to your container view.