# How paint small rectangels on a canvas on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, ondraw

I would like to draw small rectangles on a Canvas. The problem is that the rectangles don´t get any border, so the result is just a big rectangle (containing all the small rectangles (20x20 rectangles as stated below)).

In my custom `View`, I override onDraw:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRect(getWidth(), getHeight(), 50, 50, paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            canvas.drawRect(20*j, 20*i, 50, 50, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

For Java Swing, you can just do

```
g.setColor(Color.red);
for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
       g.drawRect(20 * x, 20 * y, 20, 20);
    }
 }
```

to paint the rectangles and each rectangle will have red borders.

How can I achieve this on Android?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344497/android-canvas-draw-rectangle

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change paint style to Stroke before drawing small rectangles.
Use `mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE)` along with setting stroke width.
In your code you haven't declared paint style anywhere.
If you use `Paint.Style.FILL` it will fill the rectangle.