# Drawing an Oval in Android works, but drawing a rectangle doesn't

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I'm trying to use a `RectF` to `drawOval()` and then again to try and `drawRect()`. The oval shows up, but the rectangle does not.

```
//onDraw
RectF rectF = new RectF(300, 300, 100, 100);
canvas.drawRect(rectF, paint); //doesn't display
canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint); //displays
```

Simple question, but I have no idea why it wouldn't want to draw this shape. My only idea is that this not working so far is that drawRect doesn't like when the end points are *"before"* the starting points.

EDIT: If I switch the numbers is works, but I need it to be able to accept any numbers, since in my actual application the numbers are dynamically input from the touch point of the user.

```
//onDraw
RectF rectF = new RectF(100, 100, 300, 300); //switched the coordinates
canvas.drawRect(rectF, paint); //displays
canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint); //displays
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Maybe add some logs to see if things are properly creating...

Comment: look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344497/android-canvas-draw-rectangle

Comment: @MartinPfeffer I'm not sure what you are referring to in that question. I am using a properly initialized paint object.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it... My fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to handle the points so that they conform to RectF.

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html

```
Note: most methods do not check to see that the coordinates are sorted correctly (i.e. left <= right and top <= bottom).
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks. I can't believe I missed that. Sure enough there was a sort function belonging to RectF.