# How to make a Square progress-bar with changing color in certain time interval?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

[image: Progress Bar]

I want a square progressbar like in above images, which should change color at certain condition.
Exactly like zynga poker.
lets take total duration is 6 seconds.

2sec-green

2sec-yellow

2sec-red

[As this](https://github.com/mrwonderman/android-square-progressbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use canvas for making a custom view like this. For more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

**Example**
[Android canvas draw rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344497/android-canvas-draw-rectangle)

**Logic**
You need to draw 4 lines, then start erasing them using timer. After each line is erased completely, change color of other lines, and so on.

Comment: New to this concept , can you please provide me any sample code. thanks

Comment: @Biswatma If you want code for your work, I can't do that. But I can provide you some reference code for canvas.