# How to create Progress Bar like Image in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, progress-bar

How to create below Image type of Progress ring in my Android app. I Want to show it 10 second before my whole app is loading on device. and also I want to rotate it. like window device rotate. Any Help be appreciated. I am new to Andorid.

Image :

[image]

Comment: You can use liabrary https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar

Comment: I Want ring like windows device not ProgressBar..

Comment: CircularProgressBar thickness is more in this library..

Comment: check library you can reduce by using this fnc - strokeWidth(8f) OR In xml app:cpb_stroke_width="4dp"

Comment: But I want ring which is making by dot. I Hope you understand.

Comment: @Harshad  https://github.com/Fichardu/CircleProgress this link lilttle bit match with your requirment

Comment: did u see my answer harshad

Comment: @VishalHalani I don't won't that type CircleProgress.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the perfect answer.

Using this link I found the round progress ring.

[progress_bar.gif](http://preloaders.net/preloaders/360/Velocity.gif)

Then I Use this code :

**animation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

In My main xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"          android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar1"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@anim/animation"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally output is :

[image]

Comment: But with this answer you won't get this Slow-Fast-Slow-... rotation effect just like in this GIF.
I would suggest you to use this GIF only and show it for your desired time (for this I believe you already have written the code)

Comment: @AnkitBansal if you use an `AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator` it will animate with a slow-fast-slow pattern.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Yes, almost forgot that

Answer (score 5):

u Can use the gifView library :https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

use this is your .xml:-

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/src_anim"
    />
```

where src_anim is your loader gif file

Comment: I try your answer but in output that give me left and right side arraow.

Comment: <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/progress_bar"
        android:background="@anim/animation"
        />

Comment: please remove the android:background attribute

Comment: also use the version 1.1.11 as 1.1.12 has some weird crash issue

Answer (score 4):

[Modifying the resource image of Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536075/modifying-the-resource-image-of-progress-bar/34571113#34571113) - this question recently has been discussed here. Check it out.

In short - you can use

- custom drawable
- animation-list

Both approaches allows to create progress bar like yours.

Comment: that work fine +1 for that  how to make round shape like my image I updated my question.

Comment: Rect  work fine in other activity but this give me error when I am using in Splash Activity.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this library to do it in a easier way. Furthermore, so many intuitive progressBar's type is available for you as well.

https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView

Answer (score 1):

Use **Lottie** animation.
See: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android
The LottieDrawable from library contains method **progress()**, which sets right frame if loaded image is progress image.