# Android: draw rectangle in AsyncTask of Service

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rectangles

How can a rectangle be drawn in AsyncTask of service?
Is it possible?

From [Android canvas draw rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344497/android-canvas-draw-rectangle), it said

```
    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    setContentView(drawView);
```

However, setContentView is a method of Activity. How can I do it in service asynctask?

Comment: you can draw rectangle only in methods like `View#onDraw`

Answer (score 0):

I cant see why you want to do this in an Async task, firstly you can't modify the UI thread from the doInBackground method. secondly this doesn't look like a big enough task to warrant putting it on the background thread