# How to draw rectangle frame in android

Tags: android, canvas, android-drawable, rectangles

I want to draw a square shape every time I can use it. The barcode shown is only representative. I want to make a drawing that I can give the dimensions of the square like the picture. how can I do that ? what can i research? I would like to do this by assigning measures in the MainActivity class that I write to a specific class.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwFxm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOpH1.png)

Answer (score 2):

Make a drawable with the following xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

This will generate a solid black rectangle, if you want a rectangle with borders around it use this code instead:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
    <stroke android:color="#c4441d" android:width="5dp" />
</shape>
```

once you have made the drawable, say rect.xml. You can use it in your layout as follows:

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"   
   android:src="@drawable/rect" />
```

More details here: http://devdeeds.com/how-to-create-rectangle-shape-using-xml-in-android/

If you want to do it within code, please take a look at this existing question: [Android canvas draw rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344497/android-canvas-draw-rectangle)

Comment: Is it the same as what I wrote and what you wrote? do you send me a picture