# Tensorflow - Edit image to print out location of bounding boxes?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have an android application and I've integrated my own custom tensorflow lite model.

I can print out the object category and probability score but I'm at a loss on how to draw the bounding boxes of the object on the image that is uploaded.

Here is my code that I have where I set the image into a ImageView.

```
 // SET THE IMAGE
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 100)
        {
            imageBox.setImageURI(data.getData());

            Uri uri = data.getData();
            try {
                img = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is where I am integrating the model.

```
predictBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img, 128, 128, true);

                try {
                    Android model = Android.newInstance(getApplicationContext());

                    // Creates inputs for reference.
                    TensorImage image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(img);

                    // Runs model inference and gets result.
                    Android.Outputs outputs = model.process(image);
                    Android.DetectionResult detectionResult = outputs.getDetectionResultList().get(0);

                    // Gets result from DetectionResult.
                    float score = detectionResult.getScoreAsFloat();
                    RectF location = detectionResult.getLocationAsRectF();
                    String category = detectionResult.getCategoryAsString();

                    // Releases model resources if no longer used.
                    model.close();
                    // here we will print out the results of the object to text views based on the image that is inputted by the user
                    // we print out object type and its accuracy score
                    objecttv.setText(category);
                    scoretv.setText(Float.toString(score));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Handle the exception
                }

            }
        });
```

What do I need to do to make use of `RectF location = detectionResult.getLocationAsRectF();` ?
I am using a static image and not actually tracking the movement in realtime.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer modified after question changed.**
You can draw the bounding boxes with [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas). Override onDraw() in the view where you want to draw the rectangle. **Attention, this codes only works for one bounding box. Otherwise you have to implement a for loop.** You should not call the canvas onDraw function directly from the activity. Here is a complete example:

Your tracker class:

```
// Init your canvas view
DrawView mCanvasView = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.canvasView);

// ...

predictBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img, 128, 128, true);
            try {
                Android model = Android.newInstance(getApplicationContext());
                // Creates inputs for reference.
                TensorImage image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(img);
                // Runs model inference and gets result.
                Android.Outputs outputs = model.process(image);
                Android.DetectionResult detectionResult = outputs.getDetectionResultList().get(0);
                // Gets result from DetectionResult.
                float score = detectionResult.getScoreAsFloat();
                RectF location = detectionResult.getLocationAsRectF();
                String category = detectionResult.getCategoryAsString();

                mCanvasView.drawBoundingBox()                 

                // Releases model resources if no longer used.                                   
                model.close();
                
                // here we will print out the results of the object to text views based on the image that is inputted by the user
                // we print out object type and its accuracy score
                objecttv.setText(category);
                scoretv.setText(Float.toString(score));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Handle the exception
            }
        }
});
```

Implement this canvas view:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
   Paint boxPaint;
   public static Canvas mCanvas;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        boxPaint = new Paint();            
    }

    public void drawBoundingBox() {
        // Refresh the view by calling onDraw function
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, AttributeSet attrs) {
         // Draw what you want
         boxPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
         boxPaint.setAlpha(200);
         boxPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
         canvas.drawRect(location, boxPaint);
    }
}
```

Define your Draw view in xml of your tracker class

```
<your.package.name.DrawView
    android:id="@+id/R.id.canvasView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer more? It is not very clear to me

Comment: I have updated the question in case I was not clear

Comment: I have changed my answer. I understood that you just want to draw a bounding box that you detected. This can be done quite easily with Canvas as I have shown above.

Comment: I've added it but that doesn't work for me or else I am adding it in wrong. I added the method after method just before the onClickListener ends.
Then just after the RectF location is got, I added
`Canvas canvas = new Canvas(img);
                    drawDebug(canvas,location); 
`

Comment: That's wrong. You have to get the canvas object from the view class. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344497/android-canvas-draw-rectangle. Sorry when I misunderstood you.

Comment: I have editet my answer to a full example.

Comment: It does not work , I get an @override error in the DrawView class then `Cannot resolve method 'drawBoundingBox' in Canvas `

Comment: It was just a typo.

Comment: Yeah I've played around with it now , the example doesn't work for me . I fix one error , it gives another